# HashMap's method hashCode and it's effects

Tags: java, hashmap, hashcode

I am looking in to hashing and more specifically hashMap. I do not understand the hashCode() method and would really like someone to clear it out for me. I have for the sake of a little test, written this code:

```
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    map.put(4,4);
    map.put(5,4);

    System.out.println(map.hashCode());
```

The output here is 1. However when I change it a little bit like this:

```
    map.put(2,5);
    map.put(7,4);
```

The output is 10.

How is this calculated, or how should I know without running what it would print out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you interested in HashMap's hashcode? Do you want to use the map itself as a key in another map (which would probably be a bad idea)?

Comment: It is only for learning purpose :)

Comment: It would probably be more interesting to look at how a HashMap calls its items' hashcode methods to place them in the right bucket. The hashcode of a HashMap is essentially a combination of the hashcode of its items but is not part of the hashing strategy of the HashMap itself, if you follow me.

Comment: Thanks alot. I think I can follow you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `hashCode` of a HashMap is a function of the entries in the map, but calling `map.hashCode()` as you do doesn't have much meaning.

The main use of the `hashCode` method by the `HashMap` class is to determine in which bucket of the `HashMap` a key should be stored and searched for. This is done by calling `hashCode` for the key you are putting/searching for in the `HashMap`.

BTW, here's the calculation of `hashCode` for the entries you put in your Map :

- The `hashCode` of the HashMap is the sum of the `hashCode`s of the entries.
- The `hashCode` of an `Entry` is the `hashCode` of the key XOR the `hashCode` of the value.
- The `hashCode` of an Integer is the int value.

For the first test :

```
4^4 + 5^4 = 0 + 1 = 1;
```

For the second test :

```
2^5 + 7^4 = 7 + 3 = 10;
```

Comment: So it is storing in unique way that will make it easier for you to search for? And does it just sign random values but unique ones or how does it do that?

Comment: @user3161041 `hashCode` must not return random values, since calling `hashCode` twice for an Object whose state doesn't change must return the same value. It also doesn't have to return a unique value. You should read the Javadoc of hashCode in Object class.